# Cleaner way to add routes to already defined resources :users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My routes.rb has:

```
resources :users
```

Now if I add more routes in my users_controller, is there a way to bunch them together somehow instead of having a seperate line for each new route I add?

```
resources :users

# routes for signin, signout, password_recovery that are in users_controller
```

This is rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add routes that act on the collection or individual members with the `member` and `collection` block.

See the ["Adding More RESTful Actions" section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) of the Rail's routing guide.